# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, excel

I created a plugin that export some data from the layer to some excell.

The problem that I'm facing, as the title says, is that Module xlsxwriter is not found.

To save some answers, yes I installed the module and I'm calling it with import as you can see down there.

Someone help me, I've been stuck for a long time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:\Users/STCE - Diogo Barros/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\connect_to_db\__init__.py", line 35, in classFactory
    from .connect_to_db import ConnectToDb
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users/STCE - Diogo Barros/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\connect_to_db\connect_to_db.py", line 30, in 
    from .menu import Ui_menu
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users/STCE - Diogo Barros/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\connect_to_db\menu.py", line 14, in 
    from .export_window import Ui_export_window
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users/STCE - Diogo Barros/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\connect_to_db\export_window.py", line 13, in 
    import xlsxwriter
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'


Versão do Python: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
Versão do QGIS: 3.28.1-Firenze Firenze, fde3b8fbb8c
```

> import xlsxwriter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well after some search and not being a "dummy", I found that we need to install through OsGeo4W shell.

So to simplify:

1 - Open OsGeoW shell with Admin permission

2 - pip install <package_name>

Answer (score 4):

You can also install it using command prompt. Using OsGeo4W shell is not mandatory.

- Open `cmd` in admin mode.
- Go to Python folder in which `python.exe`  is.
- Use `python -m pip install xlsxwriter`.